# Structure element is unable to assign this is asked but i coudn't get apporiate ans?

Tags: c, string, pointers, structure

hello Structure element (string )is unable to assign if it is not assign during object creation as below code why ?my code is below please help me to understand

```
 struct st
 {
   int i;
   char ch[10];
   char *ch1;
 };

  int main()
{
    struct st var2={"hello"};//this good

    struct st var;

    var.ch="hello" ; //this bad why?

    //then
    var.i=9;//is good why?

    var.ch1="hello"; //good why?
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: Use `strcpy` for it to work. Arrays can be 'initialized' ,but not 'assigned'

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart Why did you mark a c++ question as a duplicate, when this is clearly c?

Comment: @2501 AFAIK there's no canonical c question about array usage, and since VLA's aren't involved the same rules apply. I was just looking for a question that explained that arrays are not assignable. In retrospect, this would've been a better dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4978056/1530508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> struct st var2={"hello"};//this good

No, it is not good.:) You are trying to initialize integer varaiable i with pointer to the first character of string literal "Hello".

> var.ch="hello" ; //this bad why?

This is indeed bad because arrays have no assignment operator. You have to use standard function `strcpy` declared in header `<string.h>` that to copy the string literal in data member ch. For example

```
strcpy( var.ch, "hello" );
```

> ```
> var.i=9;//is good why?
>
> var.ch1="hello"; //good why?
> ```

These are good because built-in types (fundamental types) including pointers have assignment operators.

In the last statement the array that corresponds to string `literal "hello"` is converted to a pointer to its first element that is to pointer to character 'h' and this pointer is assigned to ch1.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help:
[Char array declaration and initialization in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978056/char-array-declaration-and-initialization-in-c)

There is a difference between assignment and initialization.You are doing array assignment which is not allowed and also didn't your compiler throw below error:

```
warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

for

```
struct st var2={"hello"};
```